# Configure Ember to send JSON to Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I want to send base64 image string to my server. When I send it as a parameter in my controller like this:

```
this.get('store').createRecord(Emb.Painting, {name: newName, image:base64string]});
this.get('store').commit();
```

The upload succeeds but I get RequestURITooLarge error.

How do I get ember to send my data as a JSON package?

If anyone could also explain how to recieve JSON in the rails controller thatd be great too.